# Should the deleted default constructor be in Public or Private?

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

I had to delete the default constructor to ensure that the parameterized constuctor is used always. 
That's when I wanted to know if my deleted default constructor should be under public or private access specifier.

I just wrote a sample code to test this. I tried to access the deleted default constructor.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const int val)
    {
        assign = val;
    }
private:
    A() = delete;
    int assign;
};

int main()
{
    A obj1(5);
    A obj2;
}
```

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cpp:35:7: error: ‘A::A()’ is private within this context
>
> A obj2;
>
> main.cpp:28:5: note: declared private here
>
> A() = delete;
>
> main.cpp:35:7: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A()’
>
> A obj2;
>
> main.cpp:28:5: note: declared here
>
> A() = delete;

Comment: "I had to delete the default constructor to ensure that the parameterized constuctor is used always."  No.  The default constructor is not declared if you have other constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't need to use the deleted ctor.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const int &val) : assign(val){}
private:
    int assign;
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

gives `error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’`

and

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(const int &val) : assign(val){}
private:
    int assign;
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

gives `error: use of deleted function ‘A::A()’`

- Concerning the use of delete, it could be useful with inheritance.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : assign(0){}
    A(int val) : assign(val){}
private:
    int assign;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() = delete;
    B(int val) : A(val){};
};

class C : public A
{

};

class D : public A
{
public:
    D() = delete;
};


int main()
{
    A a1; //works
    A a2(5); //works

    //B b1; -- does not work : error: use of deleted function ‘B::B()’
    B b2(3); //works

    C c1; //works, creates a default ctor
    //C c2(7); -- does not work : no matching function for call to ‘C::C(int)’

    //D d1; -- does not work :error: use of deleted function ‘D::D()’
    //D d2(2); -- does not work: error: no matching function for call to ‘D::D(int)’
    return 0;
}
```

Note that D can't be instantiated. Quite useless though :)

Comment: If that is the case, when would the deleted default constructor be useful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654927/why-explicitly-delete-the-constructor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866127/deleted-constructor-vs-no-constructor

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define default constructor with `public` access:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(const int &val) : assign(val){}
private:
    int assign;
};
```

Now you get a better error with this:

```cpp
int main (void){
    A obj;
}
```