# prohibit copy constructor and assignment operator singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton

I am implementing Singleton class in c++ and I am wondering if it is necessary to declare copy constructor and assignment operator as private, in case I have the following implementation

```
class Singleton{

static Singleton* instance;

Singleton(){}

public:


static Singleton* getInstance();

};

Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance(){

    if(instance == 0){
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

It seems that I can have only pointer to Singleton and in that case copy constructor is useless, also `operator=` . So, I can skip declaring these as private, am I wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why explicitly delete the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654927/why-explicitly-delete-the-constructor)

Comment: If you don't want those operations or they are not valid/sane for the class, then you *should* `=delete;` the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing to stop someone writing

```
Singleton hahaNotReallyASingleton = *Singleton::getInstance();
```

You can specifically [mark these functions as `delete`d](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

```
class Singleton {
    // ... other bits ...

    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete; // copy ctor
    Singleton(Singleton &&)     = delete; // move ctor
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete; // copy assignment
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&)     = delete; // move assignment
};
```

---

Note that using `delete` in this way is `C++11` and onwards - if you are stuck with an older codebase, you could make the functions `private`  (copy only, not move of course), or inherit from [`boost:noncopyable`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html) (thanks [badola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303176/badola)).

Comment: thank you, I haven't considered that case, I thought I cannot have object of that class

Comment: Kindly note that deleted functions are only allowed C++11 and above.
For pre-C++11, a construct similar to `boost::noncopyable` would be required.